# Создание массива классов с вложенным массивом классов

Tags: c#

ребят. Мне нужно создать массив класса LaneData, в котором уже вложен массив CarData. Пока что я попытался решить проблему, задав массив car (см ниже), что конечно очень криво и размер массива 99999 задан весьма неверно.

```
public class LaneData
{
    public int amount = 0;
    public int overall = 0;
    public class CarData 
    {
        public int speed;
        public int pos;
        public int time = 0;
    }
    public CarData[] car = new CarData[99999];
}
```

в самом методе я задаю массив класса LaneData следующим образом

```
    Program.LaneData[] lane = new LaneData[lanes]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < lanes; i++)
        lane[i] = new LaneData();
```

в общем-то, массив класса LaneData создается, однако ни о каком вызове вложенного массива car[] не идет и речи. Вот отрывок из кода, где я вызываю 
элемент массива car[]:

```
         for (int l = 0; l < lanes; l ++)
        {
            if (toAppear)
            {
                lane[l].amount ++;
                lane[l].overall ++;
                lane[l].car[lane[l].overall].speed = maxSpeed;
                lane[l].car[lane[l].overall].pos = roadLength;

            }
        }
```

Собственно, на строке

```
  lane[l].car[lane[l].overall].speed = maxSpeed;
```

выдается ошибка

> [System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.]

хотя lane[l].overall не выходит за рамки заданного мной размера в 99999 (вообще на момент ошибки это число равно 1).

Помогите, пожалуйста, задать массив класса CarData в массиве класса LaneData, а также сделать размер этого массива адекватным (в идеале должен зависеть от числа, задаваемого пользователем или вообще расширяться по мере необходимости в коде), а не непонятный 99999. Спасибо всем за помощь!

Comment: NullReferenceException это не про выход за пределы массива, это про то, что у вас `lane[l].car[lane[l].overall] == null`

Comment: Подсказка: `public CarData[] car = new CarData[99999];` создает массив из 99999 `null`ов

Comment: Вообще, в c# есть и другие типы, кроме массива, вы бы почитали буквари для начала - про коллекции.

Comment: Ищите в указанном дубликате подзаголовок "Элементы массива"

Comment: спасибо, я понял, где ошибка. касаемо других типов: я пытался сделать через List<>, но там вообще не было его возможно создать с привязкой списка car к определенному элементу массива lane[] (то есть список вообще как-то сам по себе существовал). не отрицаю, что я, что-то неправильно делал, но идея в том, что мне вообще не принципиально чтоб элементы CarData были массивом, главное чтоб их было много и они "принадлежали" lane'ам. спасибо большое за ответы и помощь!

Comment: `public List<int,CarData> car = new List<int,CarData>();` и не надо никаких лишних телодвижений :)